# PUT not working - BadStatusLine

Tags: json, http, robotframework

I'm using `RobotFramework` with `Selenium2Library` and `httplibrary`. All `POST` commands work fine through the terminal/cmd and through `RobotFramework`, `PUT` works in terminal/cmd, but doesn't work in `RobotFramework` and gives `BadStatusLine: ''` error.

Here's the code that i run in the terminal and it works:
`curl -i -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{ "request": { "name":"Renamed"}}' [link to the website here and an api token]`

Then I run this in the `RobotFramework` and it doesn't work:

```
Set Request Header  accept  application/json
Set Request Header  Content-type    application/json
Set Request Body    { "request": { "name":"Renamed"}}
PUT    [link]
```

I tried using waits such as `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`, but nothing helps unforunately...

Comment: from the docs I found `alias, uri, data=None, headers=None, allow_redirects=None` for `PUT`. Are you sure about the syntax of setting the body?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh yeah, i'm sure because this all works with POST method.

Comment: Well, `POST` and `PUT` are different. Some clients may not be allowed to issue a `PUT` or `DELETE` request(s).

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh i mean that the syntax in robot is the same, first you have to declare the header and then the body and then use PUT/POST/GET and so on.

Comment: BadStatusLine refers to the response from the server. Are you sure that CURL isn't getting the same bad response?

Comment: @ombre42 yep, 100% percent sure, done that a lot of times and that's why i don't understand why it doesn't work in Robot.

Comment: I would run both requests through a debugging proxy like Fiddler. Perhaps then you will see exactly what is different.

Comment: @ombre42 i can use it for web-app that i have installed locally ?

Comment: You may need to change the system-wide configuration to use the proxy server. Proxy servers are quite common and nearly everything that goes over HTTP/S can be directed through a proxy server.